# ER-Diagramm to SQL

Tags: sql, erd

I have a problem converting a sentence relating to this ER-Diagramm to SQL code. Also! I don't need to write the table just the select part:(The Diagram is in German can't help it)

what I should select:

Name aller Vorlesungen, die andere Vorlesungen voraussetzen und von Professor "Sokrates" gelesen werden. Das Ergebnis soll die Vorgaenger- und Nachfolger- Vorlesungstitel beinhalten und nach Nachfolgertitel aufsteigend sortiert sein.

translate:

Name of all lectures that require other lectures and are read by Professor "Socrates". The result should contain the previous and successor lecture titles and be sorted in ascending order by successor title.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGr8L.png)